# Get the value of the precedent day in a pivot table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pivot table of approximately 2 millions lines coming from a dataframe with the same structure as below:

```
raw = pd.DataFrame([[123456,datetime(2020,7,1),'A',10 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,1),'B',25 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,1),'C',0 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2),'A',17 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2),'B',23 ],
                   [123456,datetime(2020,7,2),'C',float('NaN') ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,2),'A',11 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,2),'B',19 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,3),'A',8 ],
                   [789012,datetime(2020,7,3),'B',21 ]], 
                   columns=['GROUP_ID','DATE', 'NAME', 'VALUE'])

    GROUP_ID    DATE    NAME VALUE
0   123456  2020-07-01   A   10.0
1   123456  2020-07-01   B   25.0
2   123456  2020-07-01   C    0.0
3   123456  2020-07-02   A   17.0
4   123456  2020-07-02   B   23.0
5   123456  2020-07-02   C    NaN
6   789012  2020-07-02   A   11.0
7   789012  2020-07-02   B   19.0
8   789012  2020-07-03   A    8.0
9   789012  2020-07-03   B   21.0
```

As you can see, the `VALUE` column can be `Nan`.
The pivot table is created like this:

```
pt = raw.pivot_table(index=['GROUP_ID', 'DATE'], columns=['NAME'], values=['VALUE'])

                      VALUE
            NAME      A      B       C
GROUP_ID    DATE            
123456  2020-07-01  10.0    25.0    0.0
        2020-07-02  17.0    23.0    NaN
789012  2020-07-02  11.0    19.0    NaN
        2020-07-03   8.0    21.0    NaN
```

The idea is to create a level 0 column `VALUE_PREV` where I can have the value of `C` for the day before.
I first did this, and it took 10 seconds:

```
dfA = pt.stack().unstack(level='DATE').shift(1, axis=1).stack(level='DATE')
dfA = dfA[dfA.index.get_level_values('NAME') == 'C']
dfA = dfA.unstack(level='NAME').rename(columns={'VALUE':'VALUE_PREV'})
ptA = pt.merge(dfA, how='outer', on=['GROUP_ID', 'DATE'])

                     VALUE                 VALUE_PREV
            NAME     A         B     C     C
GROUP_ID    DATE                
123456  2020-07-01  10.0    25.0    0.0   NaN
        2020-07-02  17.0    23.0    NaN   0.0
789012  2020-07-02  11.0    19.0    NaN   NaN
        2020-07-03   8.0    21.0    NaN   NaN
```

So I was wondering if there is a quicker way to do this or at least something less heavy to write / understand?

Edit : if the `VALUE C` is `NaN` at t, `VALUE_PREV C` at t+1 MUST be `NaN` and not 0

Comment: You might have an XY problem, why do you want the C value of the previous day? Will you also want to do the same thing for A and B values?

Comment: Because at some point after i will calculate the difference between both. I don't do the same for A et B. And thanks i didn't know this XY thing

Comment: Do you mean `pt[("VALUE_PREV","C")] = pt["VALUE"].groupby(level=0)["C"].shift()`?

Comment: It works well on my example but when i do it on the big pivot table i have less line on `ptA` than after the merging with my version, it seems that the first line with `dfa` create some lines that was not there before. I have to check if those line are important for my calculations after. But it's super fast !

Comment: @Henry Yik I did my check and the problem with your solution is that if `VALUE C` is `NaN` then `VALUE_PREV C` will be 0 then it will create some problem because if `VALUE C` of the same line is not `NaN`, it will do `x - 0 = x` instead of `x - NaN = NaN` and it will change the final value

Comment: Please do not update the question to invalidate answers. Whilst it is unfortunate that you didn't explain the entire situation when you first posted, it's unfair to answerers to have their hard work invalidated because of a mistake that was not theirs.

Comment: I wanted to avoid to post a very close question of this one but i'll do it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can check for your conditions with [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
pt = raw.pivot_table(index=['GROUP_ID', 'DATE'], columns=['NAME'], values=['VALUE'])

s = pt["VALUE"].groupby(level=0)["C"].shift()

pt[("VALUE_PREV","C")] = s.where(s.notnull(), np.NaN)

print (pt)

                    VALUE            VALUE_PREV
NAME                    A     B    C          C
GROUP_ID DATE                                  
123456   2020-07-01  10.0  25.0  0.0        NaN
         2020-07-02  17.0  23.0  NaN        0.0
789012   2020-07-02  11.0  19.0  NaN        NaN
         2020-07-03   8.0  21.0  NaN        NaN
```

Comment: thanks, i have to wait one day to give you the bounty